# Zurb Foundation 4 Icon Fonts Setup

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, icon-fonts

hope things are going well.

I'm currently building html/css prototype for a website using Zurb Foundation 4. I'm currently just using Sublime Text 3 and internet browsers to build this. I'm very interested in using the Zurb Foundation Icon sets, but I'm currently unable to get them to display. While I have Scout for sass installed, I'm hoping to just continue using the text editor and browser to build up this prototype. While I was able to download the icon package from the Zurb Foundation website, I'm not clear on how to structure these files into my current project. My project as the following folder/file structure:

- css (contains foundation.css, foundation.min.css, normalize.css)
- img (contains .gitkeep)
- js (contains foundation and vendor js files)
- index.html

the Zurb Foundation icons come with various file types including .css, .eot, .svg, .woff, and others, including a folder called "svgs" where these icon fonts seem to be housed. I've attempted to do the following:

1. Place contents of the zurb foundation icon font folder into css of my project
2. Linked foundation icon style sheet on the html page
3. In the html I typed "" to test an icon

While the panel housing icon did get slightly larger, the icon did not appear. Is it possible to use the icon fonts with running and compiling sass? Could i purely do it html/css or do I need gem and compass running? I'm comfortable with using icon fonts and implementing, but I'm just not sure how to set it up.

Could anyone please suggest a folder structure and simple instructions how do properly add the files included in the foundations-icon package to a basic zurb project (such the basic project that you receive when downloading zurb foundation from their site)?

Thank you in advance, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the icons to work. I placed the foundation icons package contents into a separate folder. I actually wasn't targeting the icons correctly. While the Zurb Foundation example referred to an example icon as general `foundicon-settings`, the SVG icons have names such as `fi-clipboard-notes` or `fi-calendar`. I added CSS classes to my custom style sheet so that I could quickly adjust the size of the icon by utilizing font-size of the element.